# how to pass values from multiple textfields with same name attributes to a variable in form of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am building a form that passes a set of numbers in form of an array to a variable as seen below

```
  var users=["1","2"];
```

the main purpose of this is to then make an Ajax request with these numbers and get their corresponding content in my database which I then pass to their respective divs, please see below

```
 var users=["1","2"];
   
var async_request=[];
var responses=[];
for(i in users)
{
    // you can push  any aysnc method handler
    async_request.push($.ajax({
        url:'back.php', // your url
        method:'post', // method GET or POST
        data:{user_name: users[i]},
        success: function(data){
            console.log('success of ajax response')
            responses.push(data);
          
        }
    }));
}


$.when.apply(null, async_request).done( function(){
    // all done
    console.log('all request completed')
    console.log(responses);
      $( '#responses' ).html(responses[1]);
      $( '#responses1' ).html(responses[0]);
       
});
```

This works perfectly.

But now I want to make some adjustments to my solution specifically

Im looking to replace the method of passing the numbers to the variable users

**from**

```
  var users=["1","2"];   // Im looking to replace the method
```

**to this**

```
var users = $('[name="tom[]"]').val(attachArray);

 <input type="text" name="tom[]" value="1" /><br>
        <input type="text" name="tom[]" value="2" /><br>
```

but I am unable to get the the ids from the two textfields and then pass to my database using my Ajax script as I did before with this

```
  var users=["1","2"];
```

Comment: You might want to think about switching to more modern methods of async data-fetching. [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) and [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await).

Comment: hello @Andy is this something you can post as an answer. Thanks

Comment: Not really because your code works, and it wouldn't be an answer to your question. Just have a look at the documentation.

Comment: okay great, thanks @Andy

Answer (score 0):

You mean

```js
const arr = ["1", "2"]
$('[name^=tom]').val(function(i) {
  return arr[i]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="tom[]" value="" /><br>
<input type="text" name="tom[]" value="" /><br>
```

or

```
$('[name^=tom]').each(function() { 
  async_request.push($.ajax({        
    url:'back.php',
    method:'post', 
    data:{user_name: this.value },
```

Comment: why do we need the constant arr? all I want is to replace that method of passing the arrays manually

Comment: okay let me explain again. initial I passed my array directly to my variable. but I want to change the method and ditch passing it manually this way "var arr = ["1", "2"]" for  passing it through textfields with their values. my expectation was to not see  this "var arr = ["1", "2"]" anymore but "var arr = textfield method

Comment: what I mean is I want to populate my variable "users" from textfields "<input type="text" name="tom[]" value="" />" but then in form of an array. just as i did manually in the first instance

Comment: great exactly, I think this should work , I was not sure on how to do it. can you fit this into the answer your provided so I can vote it up. cheers

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to use `input` key value :

```
var users = $('input[name="tom[]"]').val();
```